# If $X$ follows a distribution, can the expectation of any $E[X^t]$ be written as a function of the parameters of the distribution?

Tags: statistics

Suppose random variable $X$ follows a known (but undisclosed) continuous distribution with parameters $\theta_1, \ldots \theta_k$.

Is it guaranteed that $E[X^t]$ (if it exists) for any $t \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written as a function of the parameters of the distribution?

Intuitively, this seems to be true, since $X$ can be described completely by the distribution. But how do you show this?

Comment: Yes... there's nothing to show. The function $(\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_k) \mapsto E[X_{\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_k}^t]$ is such a function.

Comment: $E(X^t)=\int_Rx^tdF_{\theta_1,...\theta_k}(x)$.